# Using MinimumBandwidthOrdering to restructure a correlation matrix

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

I am trying to restructure a correlation matrix such that  the variables with the strongest correlations are grouped together

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
```

These are the column headers of the data'

```
t = {"Age", "Blood Pressure", "Specific Gravity", "Albumin", "Sugar","Red Blood Cells"}
```

This is the data

```
m={{1.,0.131701,-0.107092,0.0781839,0.188485,-0.00275326},{0.131701,1.,-0.123132,0.122221,0.189071,-0.149835},{-0.107092,-0.123132,1.,-0.502224,-0.291435,0.269056},{0.0781839,0.122221,-0.502224,1.,0.286883,-0.394184},{0.188485,0.189071,-0.291435,0.286883,1.,-0.0923074},{-0.00275326,-0.149835,0.269056,-0.394184,-0.0923074,1.}}
```

These are the ticks for the matrix plot

```
ticks = {{Table[{i, t[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@t}], None}, {None, 
Table[{i, Rotate[columnHeaders[[i]], 90 Degree]}, {i, 1, 
  Length@t}]}};
```

and here is the correlation matrix

```
matplot =MatrixPlot[m, Mesh -> True,ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}],FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

I am attempting to use MinimumBandwidthOrdering[] to essentially restructure the matrix so that the strongest correlated varibales are grouped together.

```
{r, c} = MinimumBandwidthOrdering[m]
```

Plotting the matrices side by side

```
{MatrixPlot[m], MatrixPlot[m[[r, c]]]}
```

My problem is this: How can i plot the the matrices such that when the matrix is transformed, the column headers that are associated with that variable are transformed with it.

from the plots, it is just labelled as: 1,2,3,4,5,6
Whereas i was hoping it to be in the format of the plot that was given from the matplot function.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: With `t[[c]]`...?

Comment: If you mean t[[c]] as in the collum headers appended  to the collums yes. But with t appended to  the columns and rows as shown in the plot from the matplot[] correlation matrix.

Comment: use `ticks2 = {{Table[{i, t[[r]][[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@t}], None}, {None, 
    Table[{i, Rotate[t[[c]][[i]], 90 Degree]}, {i, 1, Length@t}]}};` for `FrameTicks` in `MatrixPlot` of `m[[r,c]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `ticks2` using `t[[r]]` and `t[[c]]` in place of `t` in your code for `ticks`.

```
ticks2 = {{Table[{i, t[[r]][[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@t}], None}, {None, 
    Table[{i, Rotate[t[[c]][[i]], 90 Degree]}, {i, 1, Length@t}]}};

Row[MapThread[Panel @
   MatrixPlot[#, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, 
     ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}], 
     FrameTicks -> #2, 
     Epilog -> {Text[Style[#3, 16], Scaled@{-.15, 1.15}]}] &, 
  {{m, m[[r, c]]}, {ticks, ticks2}, {"m", "m[[r, c]]"}}], Spacer[20]]
```

[image]